# Keep website-tab navigation within MSTeams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm creating an app that should go in the left app-bar that should load our intranet (hosted on sharepoint online).
I followed the documentation and created a package; when I add it to the sidebar it does load the first page of the site.
Any link I click will open in the default browser, instead of in the teams client itself.
Is it possible to either directly open the browser, either to keep the navigation in Teams?

```
{"$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",

"version":"1.0.0","manifestVersion":"1.9","id":"abb685ff-xxxx-4d9c-97ec-875b5ec946fd",
"packageName":"com.package.name",
"name":{
    "short":"xxxx",
    "full":"xxxx"
    },
"developer":{
    "name":"xxxx",
    "mpnId":"",
    "websiteUrl":"https://zzz.com",
    "privacyUrl":"https://zzz.com/privacy-statement",
    "termsOfUseUrl":"https://zzz.com/disclaimer"},
    "description":{
        "short":"access to xxx Intranet",
        "full":"access to xxx Intranet"
        },
    "icons":{
        "outline":"outline.png",
        "color":"color.png"
        },
    "accentColor":"#add1cb",
    "staticTabs":[
        {
            "entityId":"4d62815a-xxxx-4b36-9ba3-79e67797963d",
            "name":"xxxx",
            "contentUrl":"https://xxxx.sharepoint.com",
            "websiteUrl":"https://xxxx.sharepoint.com",
            "scopes":["personal"]
        },
        {
            "entityId":"about",
            "scopes":["personal"]
            }],
        "validDomains":[]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is by design and nothing can be done. You can try adding [SharePoint directly as a tab in Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-sharepoint-page-list-or-document-library-as-a-tab-in-teams-131edef1-455f-4c67-a8ce-efa2ebf25f0b)